# Ошибка при разделении файлов settings.py в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose

Добый день, пытаясь разделить настройки Django наткнулся на проблему в которой не могу найти причину.

Вот моя структура проекта:

```
├── app
│   ├── myapplication
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── base.py
│   │   │   ├── docker.py
│   │   │   └── local.py
│   │   ├── celery.py
│   │   ├── constants.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   │   ├── media
│   │   ├── static
│   ├── manage.py
│   └── start-celery.sh
├── docker-compose.local.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
└── requirements.txt
```

Как видно у меня есть два файла настроек, одна `(docker.py)` нужна для того чтобы запускать проект с помощью `docker-compose up` команды, а вторая для локального запуска проекта с помощью командной строки `python manage.py runserver --settings=myapplication.settings.local`.

Помимо этого у меня есть два файла `docker-compose`:

- docker-compose.yml
- docker-compose.local.yml

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=myapplication.settings.docker"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=myapp
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=secretpassword
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=myapp
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secretpassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Первая служит для полноценного запуска проекта с помощью команды `docker-compose up`

*docker-compose.local.yml*

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=myapp
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secretpassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    hostname: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

А вторая для запуска редиса и базы данных, чтобы вдальнейшем можно было запустить с помощью командной строки.

Так вот при запуске с помощью команды `docker-compose up` я получаю ошибку

`app_1    | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`

И данную ошибку я начал получать только после разделения конфигурационных файлов:

мой конфигурационный файл `docker.py`:

```
try:
    from .base import *
except ImportError:
    pass

DEBUG = True

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', ]

MEDIA_ROOT = '/vol/web/media'
STATIC_ROOT = '/vol/web/static'
```

А вот и настройки `local.py`

```
try:
    from .base import *
except ImportError:
    pass

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', ]

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        "NAME": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_DB", "postgres"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USER", "postgres"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_HOST", "localhost"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PORT", 5432),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
    }
}

MEDIA_ROOT = '/media'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static'
```

Я в обе конифигурационные файлы назначал SECRET_KEY, но все было бестолку, и все равно я получаю данную ошибку.. Прошу мне помочь найти причину появления данной ошибки.

Comment: `except ImportError: pass` — вот это вы конечно зря

Comment: А ещё вы очень зря запускаете runserver на продакшене в докере, так как документация Django это категорически запрещает

Comment: Я пробовал и без `try/except` результат один и тот же

Comment: Да вот я знаю что так нельзя, и поэтому хочу в докере запускать только базу данных и редис, но разделение на подобное привело меня к ошибкам которые я не могу исправить

Comment: А вообще возможно вы забыли прописать `--settings` для команды migrate

Comment: @andreymal Я добавил, все равно такую же ошибку выдает..

Comment: @E1mir а как на счёт команд?  В django есть возможность добавлять свои команды на manage.py. Там все импорты нормально пройдут, которые в продакшене работают.